# xrandr "Failed to get size of gamma for output default" with xserver-xorg-video-dummy on a headless NUC/BACE in 18.04

Tags: xorg, display-resolution, xrandr, headless

I am trying to set up Ubuntu 18.04 on a NUC-like Gigabyte BACE. Everything works perfect. BUT: I would like to use Gnome with a screen resolution of 1680x1050.

This is what I did:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-dummy
sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/xorg.conf
```

and there

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Configured Video Device"
    Driver      "dummy"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "Configured Monitor"
    HorizSync 31.5-48.5
    VertRefresh 50-70
    Modeline "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Default Screen"
    Monitor     "Configured Monitor"
    Device      "Configured Video Device"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
    Depth 24
    Modes "1680x1050_60.00"
    EndSubSection
EndSection`
```

But when I connect (via Anydesk) I get a screen resolution of 1360x768.

Here is the output of `xrandr` (the word "failed" is mentioned):

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 240, current 1360 x 768, maximum 1360 x 768
default connected primary 1360x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1360x768      60.00* 
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.00    56.00  
   640x480       60.00  
   684x384       60.00  
   680x384       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00  
   480x270       60.00  
   400x300       60.00    56.00  
   320x240       60.00
```

Furthermore, I try to set up the screen resolution manually. But

```
xrandr --newmode "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync
```

gives me

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
```

What can I do? Did I miss out anything?

Thanks, Joachim

OK

XORG troubleshooting starts with

```
cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

it shows

```
[ 86133.223] _XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
[ 86133.223] _XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
[ 86133.223] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[ 86133.223] (EE) Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running(EE) 
[ 86133.224] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[ 86133.224] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[ 86133.224] (EE) 
[ 86133.224] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

[XORG docs](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.0/doc/xorg.conf.5.html) specify a gamma-value in the "Monitor Section".